# How to assign a struct to an array of pointers of the struct?

Tags: c++, struct

Okay. So I have the following struct:

```
struct pkt {
    int seqnum;
    int acknum;
    int checksum;
    char payload[20];
};
```

Now I have the following variables:

```
struct pkt packet;
struct pkt* packets[1000];
```

Now after a few manipulations of `packet` I am trying to assign it to an array cell as follows:

```
packets[counter++] = (pkt*)&packet;
```

But that is somehow changing all the cells of the array upon a new assignment to the value of the new assignment.

What am I doing wrong?

I have just started off with C, so I am not so familiar with pointers and addresses.

**EDIT**: The function in which the assignment is being done:

```
void A_output(struct msg message)
{
    struct pkt packet;
    packet.acknum = 0;
    packet.seqnum = 0;
    memset(&packet.payload, '\0', 20);
    memcpy((char*)&packet.payload, (char*)&message.data, 20);
    memset(&packets[counter]->payload, '\0', 20);
    packets[counter++] = (pkt*)&packet;
    printAll();

    if(nextseq < winbase + winsize) {
        packets[nextseq]->seqnum = nextseq;
        setChecksum(packets[nextseq]);
        tolayer3(0, *packets[nextseq]);

        if(winbase == nextseq) 
            starttimer(0, increment);
        nextseq++;
    }
}
```

Since the value is coming as a parameter of a function, doesn't it have a new memory address every time?

Comment: Okay. So you don't understand what a *pointer* is?

Comment: You are assigning the same address for all packets, I don't think that's yur intent.

Comment: Time to take a deep breath and re-read the C book. Don't rush.

Comment: @SouravGhosh given the `struct` only has a tag name and is referred by that (without `struct` keyword), this is C++ -- adjusted tags. But nevermind, reading a book will help.

Comment: BTW, voted to close because this is a question seeking for debugging help, but doesn't include a [mcve].

Comment: Yes. I somehow get that. And no that's not my intention. 
@FelixPalmen: I do understand what it is. But I haven't used them much in practice. This is the second ever program I am writing in C and the situation is such that I do not have the time to go through the basics of C that I might be comfortable enough.

Comment: @Manic What about using `std::vector<pkt> packets(1000);`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm sorry, why's this not be C? What did I miss? (2 VTC's now, BTW.)

Comment: Nope. Can't use vector. No marks for using vector.

Comment: @SouravGhosh `packets[counter++] = (pkt*)&packet;` <- `pkt` is a struct tag here and only names a type in C++, not in C.

Comment: @Manic _"Can't use vector."_ Silly restriction.

Comment: @Manic "*I do not have the time to go through the basics of C*" -- well, that's though.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah, the cast? that's redundant, at best, and maybe who knows, thres's a typedef too...but you're right, in general.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I have a networking assignment to submit tomorrow. I am doing my MS in CS. I have done my Bachelor's in Chemical Engineering. Does it get any better? But then, hey, I can code. But all I have ever coded in is Java. So, you see!

Comment: @SouravGhosh OP is free to change the tag to C if it is indeed C ... but there's no reason at all to tag this question with two language tags :)

Comment: @Manic it's still not a [mcve]. The function doesn't contain the line `packets[counter++] = (pkt*)&packet;`, it accesses an existing (?) element. Where is the memory for these elements allocated? If your assignment is due tomorrow, you probably should have started earlier. We could answer a well-asked question here, but it's impossible to help if you lack basic understanding of the language.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it again. I was changing the code whilst looking for help here. So. Sorry about that. @FelixPalmen

Comment: @Manic now, the code is just wrong: your `packets` is an array of *pointers*, but you assign a struct  with `packets[counter++] = packet;`. The compiler should reject that.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh. Jesus! I think I should sleep. Corrected that though!

Comment: @Manic well, now it's possible to answer, which I did. Please keep in mind for the next time you ask a question to create a [mcve] (if it's a question seeking debugging help) from the beginning, so you won't get these downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void A_output(struct msg message)
{
    struct pkt packet;

[...]

    packets[counter++] = (pkt*)&packet;
```

This last line assigns the address of a variable with *automatic storage duration* (a local variable) to an object with *static storage duration* (a global). Once your function exits, the variable with automatic storage duration **doesn't exist anymore**, therefore the pointer doesn't point to a valid location. Using this pointer later is **undefined behavior**, but it's quite likely that your function reuses the same memory location for your `struct pkt packet` every time it is invoked, leading to the behavior you describe.

What you have to do is for example allocate memory for every element in `packets` with `malloc()` or `new`:

```
struct pkt *packet = malloc(sizeof *packet); // C style
// or:
pkt *packet = new pkt(); // C++ style

[...] // fill *packet

packets[counter++] = packet;
```

Don't forget to `free()` (C) or `delete` (C++) all the packets when you're done.

On a side note, in your original code, the cast `(pkt*)` is redundant. `&packet` already has the type `struct pkt *`. But as this is wrong anyways, it doesn't matter much here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all the cells in the array have the value of `&packet`, which is a single value. They all point to the same address, so of course they all point to the same value.

You can dynamically allocate the memory, or much better, just make `packets` a `pkt[]` - an array of regular packets and then assignment to one of the cells will preform copy of all the values to another memory, not copy of pointer.

As for the question if `packet` always has the same address, I cannot know for sure (My guess is that it does) but you could check - print the value of `&packet` every time the function is called and see if it changes.

P.S. `packet` isn't a function argument, but a local function variable.

Comment: `packet` is coming as a parameter of a function. So isn't it coming as a new value every time?

Comment: It depends. Could you include the full function and the function that calls it?

Comment: @Manic that's why you're supposed to create a [mcve]: We can't know! -- Neo, don't answer questions that are (still?) unclear, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- "answer well-asked questions".

Comment: @FelixPalmen Edited the post.

Comment: @Manic Where is `packets` defined?

Comment: @Neo `packets` is defined as a global.

Comment: And where is the assignment line? (`packets[counter++]...`)?

Comment: @Neo Sorry about that. Please check now!

Answer (score 1):

```
packets[0] = &pkt;
```

Gives

```
 +-----+           +-------+
 | 0   | ========> | [pkt] |
 +-----+           +-------+
```

Then

```
packets[1] = &pkt;
```

Gives

```
 +-------+              +----------+
 |    0  |  ==========> |  [pkt]   |
 +-------+         ||=> +----------+
 |    1  |  =======* 
 +-------+
```

There is one underlying object (pkt), which is referred to in two places in the array.

If you want their values to be distinct, then make the array an array of full members.

```
struct pkt packets[1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to create an array of structures. The below code snippet creates a local array of structures which each contain an array of integers.

The method acts on the array of structures individually, assigning unique values to the integer array inside.

```
// Structure definitions
#define NUM_OF_VALUES 2
#define NUM_OF_STRUCTS 5

typedef struct {
    uint value[NUM_OF_VALUES];
} Test_Struct_t;

// local object
static Test_Struct_t struct_array[NUM_OF_STRUCTS];

// Function settings values in local object.
void struct_foo(void)
{
     for (uint idx = 0; idx < NUM_OF_STRUCTS; idx++)
     {
         for (uint jdx = 0; jdx < NUM_OF_VALUES; jdx++)
         {
             struct_array[idx].value[jdx] = (idx + jdx);
         }
     }
}
```

> Since the value is coming as a parameter of a function, doesn't it
>   have a new memory address every time?

The function parameter(s) will be pushed to the stack when the function is called. If you want the variable you are parsing to retain its value after you operate on it, use a [pointer argument instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698317/c-pointers-as-function-arguments)