# Returning const char * via function parameter

Tags: c

Trying to create a getter for `const char *` type where return type is not `char char *` (i.e. returned via parameter). However, when return from `get_MyName()`, `ptr_name` remains `NULL`.

```
typedef enum {FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, MAX_NAMES} NAME_CHOICES;

const char *MyNames[MAX_NAMES] = {
  "Jon",
  "Steve",
};

size_t get_MyName(const char *my_name, NAME_CHOICES my_choice) {
  my_name = MyNames[my_choice];
  return sizeof(MyNames[my_choice]);
}

int main() {
  const char *ptr_name = NULL;

  get_MyName(ptr_name, FIRST_NAME);

  printf("%s\n", ptr_name);
}
```

During the run, `ptr_name` is passed to `get_MyName()` as `my_name` and `my_name` is set to the appropriate pointer. However, after return from the function, 'ptr_name' remains `NULL`.

```
1. ptr_name == NULL
2. pass ptr to get_MyName()
3. ptr set to 0 index of char ptr array (ptr to 'J' in 'Jon')
4. size returned (char ptr => 1 byte)
5. ptr_name printed as null
```

Is this the correct approach when attempting a 'get' assuming the return type must be something else? If so, what is missing? If not, how should this problem be approached?

Comment: Need a pointer to pointer.

Comment: Variables are passed by value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698317/pointers-as-function-arguments-in-c

Comment: And the `sizeof` you return also isn't what you think it is.

Comment: sizeof() here is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the address of pointer. Below code should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, MAX_NAMES} NAME_CHOICES;

const char *MyNames[MAX_NAMES] = {
  "Jon",
  "Steve",
};

size_t get_MyName(const char **my_name, NAME_CHOICES my_choice) {
  *my_name = MyNames[my_choice];
  return sizeof(MyNames[my_choice]);
}

int main() {
  const char *ptr_name = NULL;

  get_MyName(&ptr_name, FIRST_NAME);

  printf("%s\n", ptr_name);
}
```