# How can I read data from user using a struct variable in a function

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, struct

I am a complete newbie. When I run the program and enter the data the throw function only displays integer value correctly but does not display the characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student_data{
    char name[20],department[10];
    int roll_num[0];
};
void collect(struct student_data data);
void throw(struct student_data student1);
int main(void){
    struct student_data student1;
    collect(student1);
    throw(student1);
    return 0;
}
void collect(struct student_data data1){
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf(" %s",data1.name);
    printf("Enter department:");
    scanf(" %s",data1.department);
    printf("Enter roll number:");
    scanf(" %d",data1.roll_num);
}

void throw(struct student_data student1){

    printf("%s\n",student1.name);
    printf("%s\n",student1.department);
    printf("%d\n",student1.roll_num[0]);
}
```

Comment: Arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means they are *copied*, and the argument variable is then disconnected from the variables used when calling the functions. Modifying the local copy inside the function will not modify the original. You should probably learn about *pointers* and how to *emulate pass by reference in C*.

Comment: with `int roll_num[0];` you make an array with space for 0 integers. If you only need 1 value, stick with a simple variable: `int roll_num;`; if you need an array use 1 or more elements: `int roll_num[3]; /* roll_num[0], roll_num[1], and roll_num[2] */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that, in C programming language, arguments are passed by value. When you create an instance of your struct in the main function as `struct student_data student1;` and then pass it to the functions `collect()` and `throw()`, you are just passing it as value which means there will be created a copy of that instance in the function and when the function is destroyed, the copy will also be destroyed and it will never affect your real instance which you created in the main function. To prevent it, you need to use pointers. Check the code below;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student_data{
    char name[20],department[10];
    int roll_num;
};

void collect(struct student_data *data);
void throw(struct student_data *student1);

int main(void){
struct student_data *student1;
collect(&student1);
throw(&student1);
return 0;
}

void collect(struct student_data *data1){
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf(" %s",&data1->name);
    printf("Enter department:");
    scanf(" %s",&data1->department);
    printf("Enter roll number:");
    scanf(" %d",&data1->roll_num);
}

void throw(struct student_data *student1){

printf("%s\n",student1->name);
printf("%s\n",student1->department);
printf("%d\n",student1->roll_num);


}
```

Comment: Thanks man.I completely forgot that arguments are passed by value. I am currently studying pointers although having a bit of trouble understanding them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify, inside your function `collect()`,  data that is passed to it, you need to the pass a reference to the data, and not the data itself. See this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698317/pointers-as-function-arguments-in-c) for an idea of how to do that.
Therefore, you'll make the following changes:

use `void collect(struct student_data *data)` instead of `void collect(struct student_data data)`, and in `main()`, use `collect(&student1)` instead of `collect(student1)`.

Your use of  `roll_num`is a little dodgy so I am ignoring it. Below is the modified version of relevant parts of your code:

```
int main(void){
   struct student_data student1;
   collect(&student1);
   throw(student1);
  return 0;
}
void collect(struct student_data *data1){
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf(" %s",data1->name);
    printf("Enter department:");
    scanf(" %s",data1->department);
//    printf("Enter roll number:");
//    scanf(" %d",data1->roll_num);
}
```