# How do I use pointers to access and use different values in a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need help with using pointers to access 2 different values from the function I created. I would need these values for certain calculations in a separate function.

I have tried introducing a pointer in the function and assigning the inductance to it. But it's not printing anything.

This is my initial code before adding in the pointers.

```
 double values(double, double);

 int main(void)
 {
  values(a,b);

  system("PAUSE");

  return 0;

 }

 double values(double inductance, double capacitance)   
 {
   //a = inductance; b = capacitance

   printf("Please insert the inductance value (in mH):\n");
   scanf("%lf", &inductance);



  printf("Please insert the capacitance value (in microFarads):\n");
  scanf("%lf", &capacitance);

  printf("\n");
  }
```

This is one of the things I tried. I tried several others. But I ended up confusing myself even more.

```
  double values(double *inductance) 
  {

  double induct;

   printf("Please insert the inducatance value (in mH):\n");
   scanf("%lf", induct);

   *inductance = induct;

   //   printf("\n \n %p", induct);

    printf("\n");
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698317/pointers-as-function-arguments-in-c)

Comment: `scanf("%lf", induct);` --> `scanf("%lf", &induct);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double values(double);

 int main(void)
 {
  double a;
  values(&a);//<----Send a Pointer of the var(the address of )

  system("PAUSE");

  return 0;

 }

double values(double *inductance) //<----change the var value by pointer.
{

   printf("Please insert the inducatance value (in mH):\n");
   scanf("%lf", inductance );

   printf("\n");
}
```